# AJAX - Calling a function that directs to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this javascript functions,

This View function is a simple function that lets me go to my view page.

```
function View(URLPath) {
    $.ajax({
        url: URLPath,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "text"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#viewcontainer').html(data);
    });
}
```

The other one is a simple function that let me add.

```
function Add(URLPath) { 
    var data = $("#Form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        url: URLPath,
        complete: function(responseData){       
            View(ROOT_URL + '/view');
        }
    });
}
```

After I add data I want it to return to my view page. This will show that the data has been added.

So in the complete part of the Add function, I call the View function.

```
complete: function(responseData){       
        View(URL + '/view');
    }
```

The problem is it will not load. It will return me to my home page.

I think it is because the add function is in another page and when I call the View function in the complete part, It will not find the `id = #viewcontainer`.

The view page will look like this

```
<div id="viewcontainer">
HERE IS THE VIEW
</div>
```

add will look like this

```
<p>THIS IS ADD</p>
```

**EDIT** 
The files are already included.

Comment: Did you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: use ajax `success` event handler instead of `done()` - `$.ajax({url: myUrl, data..... , success: function(result) { View(myUrl); }});`

Comment: There are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your viewcontainer is in view.html and you are trying setting  $('#viewcontainer').html(data); which is in your home.html page; then it will not work as its not in the scope and unknown to the context.

Comment: There are no solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You should include `View` function where it is called. If this a `script` file include or simple copy/paste function in same page where call.

`Javascript` required function on same page when finally render on browser.

If `View(ULR)` function not found you will received an error on `console` like `function not defined`

If you function exist on same page and `div id` not found you will also receive an error on console.

Comment: It already included. No error it just returns me to the home page.

Comment: Exactly this the problem I think, you will redirected to home page and not able to see any error.

Comment: did your `Add` function work correctly means form will be saved??

Comment: Yes, It worked correctly. I can view it in the page. The only problem is when I click submit button in add, the View function doesnt work.

Comment: Yes. I cant find the mistake I made because It doest have any error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111872/discussion-between-jitendra-tiwari-and-guwop69).